# How to structure a count query that includes children

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy of message types: `Request` which can contain `Offer`s, which can contain `Dialog`s. I'm trying to query the database to determine how many of each chain contains a message that has not been read by a given User.

Here's the working query in SQL (but I'd like to be able to do it in a LINQ to Entities query, if possible):

```
SELECT      COUNT(msgID)
FROM        tblMessage
WHERE       msgTypeID = 1 // Request type
    AND     msgUserID = 7 // The creator of the Request
    AND     (       msgWhenRead IS NULL // That they didn't read the top Request, OR has any Offers, etc that haven't been read
                OR  0 < (   SELECT  COUNT(msgID)
                            FROM    tblMessage
                            WHERE   msgTypeID = 2
                            AND     msgRecipientID = 7 // Looking for Recipient here, as the creator is the person who is making the offer, but the Recipient is being set to the person who made the parent Request.
                            AND     (       msgWhenRead IS NULL
                                        OR  0 < (   SELECT  COUNT(msgID)
                                                    FROM    tblMessage
                                                    WHERE   msgTypeID = 3 // Is a Dialog
                                                    AND     msgRecipientID = 7 // Same deal with the Recipient here as with Offers.
                                                    AND     msgWhenRead IS NULL
                                                )
                                    )
                        )
            )
```

This is my attempt that is not working with EntityFramework:

```
response.Requests = repository.Messages
                              .OfType<Request>()
                              .Where(r => r.Creator.Id == request.UserId &&
                                          r.dbIsDeleted == "N" &&                                                                           
                                          r.dbStatusId != (int)RequestStatus.Inappropriate &&
                                          (     r.WhenRead == null ||
                                                r.Offers.Select(o => o.RecipientId == request.UserId && 
                                                                     o.dbIsDeleted == "N" &&
                                                                     o.dbStatusId != (int)OfferStatus.Inappropriate &&
                                                                     ( o.WhenRead == null ||
                                                                       o.Dialogs.Select(d => d.RecipientId == request.UserId &&
                                                                                             d.dbIsDeleted == "N" &&
                                                                                             d.dbStatusId != (int)DialogStatus.Inappropriate &&
                                                                                             d.WhenRead == null)
                                                                                .Any()
                                                                    ))
                                                        .Any()
                               ))
                               .Count();
```

I tried changing to `SelectMany` at both `r.Offers.Select()` and `o.Dialogs.Select()`, but was getting compiler errors. I was thinking perhaps that was the issue.

What I'm getting right now is that with everything having been read, the Entity Framework query is still finding the top Request, and I'm not sure why. The structure of the EF SQL that gets generated isn't close to that of the one I wrote myself. I can provide the EF SQL  if people think that may help.